# Distance approximation?

Tags: performance, algorithm, distance

I am doing pathfinding on a 2D grid.

I need to calculate distance as one of my heuristics.

Furthermore I need to return the closest spot if the full path is not found.

Calculating the exact distance to a double precision seems like unnecessary overhead. Is there any fast approximation I can use, which will still be accurate enough to meet my needs? (within rounding accuracy of 1)

By the way, path lengths are typically only around 5-30 nodes, so using a more accurate function at the end wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: What kind of moves are legal? (and why has no one asked that yet? knowing the moves is crucial to finding a good heuristic)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ***I need to return the closest spot if the full path is not found.***

In this case you could skip the square root operation in the distance calculation, i.e. compare squared distances using just `dy * dy + dx * dx`.

This works since *a<sup>2</sup> < b<sup>2</sup>* if and only if *a < b* for two arbitrary distances *a* and *b*.

In a 2D grid this would be implemented purely with integers.

If you need non-integer values, I'd probably go with `double`s until that proves to be a bottleneck.

Comment: It's the most demanding function of the program. Timed them. It will cause lag so yes I'm micro-optimizing. :)

Comment: Heheh.. That good to hear :) I don't have any better option than `dy*dy + dx*dx`. That will however avoid doubles any way.

Comment: @aioobe. Is it necessary to use _dy*dy + dx*dx_, or just _dy + dx_ will work? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: *dy + dx* will get the closest point in terms of Manhattan distance. I wouldn't say that that is actually the *closest* point. Consider for instance if my unit moves to a position (1,1) away from it's goal (that is, *dx* = *dy* = 1) then I'd say he's closer than if he had moved (2, 0) away from his goal. (Since the actual distance from the goal is √2.)

Comment: Thanks, voted this as the answer. I implemented it and the pathfinding is 3x faster, just in case anyone thought it is unnecessary optimizing. ;)

Comment: The solutionis correct, but the explanation "since a² < b²" is lacking info. what is a , what b?

Comment: @AlexWien, clarified.

Comment: Thanks, I wpould add: two distances, a,b and this is always true in cartesian and geographical distances.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly better than Manhattan distance and nearly as fast would be:

```
unsigned int fastDist(unsigned int dx, unsigned int dy) {
    if ( dy < dx ) return (dx + (dy >> 1));
    else return (dy + (dx >> 1));
}
```

It's exact when either dx or dy are zero. The error on the diagonal is about 6% and the maximum error is about 12%.

And this can be improved by adding another term:

```
unsigned int fastDist(unsigned int dx, unsigned int dy) {
    unsigned int w;
    if ( dy < dx ) {
        w = dy >> 2;
        return (dx + w + (w >> 1));
    }
    else {
        w = dx >> 2;
        return (dy + w + (w >> 1));
    }
}
```

This has a maximum error of less than 7% and the error along the diagonal is less than 3%.

Comment: This is a nice mechanism with odd properties I'm still trying to understand. There's a write-up here with a derivation and some refinement:  http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Fast_Approximate_Distance_Functions.shtml

Comment: In this case I'm using ( dy / 2 ). It's more readable and all modern C compilers will optimize this to down a bit shift for you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a 2D grid you could consider using the [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance).  This would allow you to work in grid units all the time and avoid the square root.  As aioobe suggests, this is probably micro-optimizing.